# How To Call A Javascript Function On Page Load

Tags: javascript, function, hash, window, onload

I have this little snippet of code in script tags, along with some functions:

```
window.onload = function()
    {
        if (window.location.hash === 'open')
        {
            $("#signinform").css("display", "block");
            $(".blackout").css("display", "block");
        }
    }
```

It's not working and I'm pretty sure its just because of a syntax error. However, I can't find it. The function is intended to be called when the page is loaded. Can you guys find the problem?

Comment: You are already using jQuery, so is there any reason you aren't using `$(document).ready(function() { /* Your code here */ });` ?

Comment: The url is ".../home.php#open". Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (window.location.hash === '#open')
```

The *hash* member of *window.location* will return the **#** sign, plus whatever string follows it.

You can detect this behavior by typing *console.log(window.location.hash)* into your console.

Additionally, since you are already using jQuery, you could potentially stick with:

```
$(function() {
```

instead of

```
window.onload
```

Answer (score 2):

window.location.hash includes the hash mark ('#').

It will never match 'open', or any string without the hashtag.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using jquery right? Try using .ready();
http://api.jquery.com/ready/

A good way to write javascript is put all your javascript code on end of your page, before `</body>`

Answer (score 0):

As you are using jquery, you can do:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if (window.location.hash === '#open')  //Inlude hash here!
    {
        $("#signinform").css("display", "block");
        $(".blackout").css("display", "block");
    }
});
```

`window.location` also works, but it takes much longer, for example if you have big images in your page, it will wait until all are loaded. `$(document).ready` doesn't have this problem.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

working just fine:

```
function loaded() {
    if (window.location.hash == '#open') alert('ok');
}
window.location.hash = 'open'
window.onload = loaded;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/acrashik/NEfR2/481/